# Android DialogFragment append text to EditText

Tags: android, string, text, dialog, android-edittext

I have a DialogFragment with an EditText. If I append a string in onCreateDialog, onActivityCreated, onStart, onResume, or onShow the string is appended every time I rotate the screen.

I want to append a string to the EditText only once (This should be the default text).

Comment: Are you using the `setText` method or `append` to set the default text? Sounds like you want the former?

Comment: I use append() and selectAll().
I want to set the default text only if the user didn't change it.

Comment: Worse case, use a boolean to track whether your command has already run once. If so, don't run it again.

Comment: Ok, I need to save it in onSaveInstanceState()?
Or it will be automaticlly restored?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `EditText` but I think you want to use the `setText` method instead to get your default text in place. If I'm misunderstanding, and you really do need to use `append()` in your case, you can make a global boolean called (for example) `hasRun`. Set it to `false` initially. Then in `onCreate', put your EditText setting commands inside an `if (!hasRun)` clause. End that clause with `hasRun = true` so that the EditText commands won't run again on screen orientation change.